# Android - Change font from file downloaded

Tags: android

I am trying to change the font of textview from the font file downloaded but the font is not changing.

```
private fun initViews() {
        askForPermission()
        binding.btnLoad.setOnClickListener {
            setTypeface()
        }
    }

private fun setTypeface() {
        val file = File("${Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)}/myfont.ttf")
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.e("LOG", "FILE EXISTS")
        } else {
            Log.e("LOG", "FILE DOESN'T EXISTS")
        }
        val typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(file.path)
        binding.tv1.typeface = typeface
    }
```

Note -

1. Font file is downloaded in the Downloads folder
2. Read/Write External permission is allowed

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you tried running in debug mode to see if `setTypeface` runs till the end without problems?

Comment: @huytc Yes it runs without any error but font doesn't change

Comment: Have you tried using another font?

Comment: @huytc I tried setting same font using assets then it was working fine

Comment: Did you try that in the XML or using `binding.tv1.typeface = typeface`? If you tried loading from assets then setting it programmatically and it succeeded, there must be some problems with loading from file and/or creating Typeface from file then.